# Breaking out of recursive function calls in matlab

Tags: matlab

The following is only a simple example to generalize and illustrate the problem I am having.

If I have a function like the following:

```
function newtraph(initialguess,funct,dfunct)
ht = funct(initialguess);
if abs(ht) < 10^(-6)
    disp(initialguess); return
elseif abs(ht) > 10^6
    disp('Fix Guess'); return
end
newtraph(initialguess-(ht/dfunct(initialguess)), funct, dfunct);
```

The only way (that I am aware of) to exit out is through the use of those return statements. But, I want to assign output from functions of this variety to variables in the base workspace. I want to do some thing like:

```
function out = newtraph(initialguess,funct,dfunct)
ht = funct(initialguess);
if abs(ht) < 10^(-6)
    out = initialguess; return
elseif abs(ht) > 10^6
    disp('Fix Guess'); return
end
newtraph(initialguess-(ht/dfunct(initialguess)), funct, dfunct);
```

This doesn't work, the `return` prevents out from being assigned.

```
Output argument "out" (and maybe others) not assigned
```

Some ideas I have for a solution are using globals or `evalin`. But is there some simpler way that I am missing. I just want pass the output from functions of this style back to the base workspace?

A test case, just in case:

```
funct=@(x) -x-cos(x); dfunct=@(x) sin(x)-1; initialguess=1;
```

Thanks for your time.

Well, I am an idiot. It was simply a case of forgetting the final assignment:

```
function out = newtraph(initialguess,funct,dfunct)
ht = funct(initialguess);
if abs(ht) < 10^(-6) %Tolerance
    out = initialguess; return
elseif abs(ht) > 10^6
    out=0; return
end
out = newtraph(initialguess-(ht/dfunct(initialguess)), funct, dfunct);
```

Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example function that doesn't work is almost there. You just need to assign

```
out = newtraph(...)
```

on the last line so you can capture the output.

You probably also need to assign out = 0 or some dummy value when you report "fix guess" so that branch of the code will also return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here: aren't you missing the assignment in the last line?  And also don't you need to initialize out in your elseif in case out wasn't assigned before?  I.e.

```
ht = funct(initialguess);
if abs(ht) < 10^(-6)
    out = initialguess;
    return
elseif abs(ht) > 10^6
    disp('Fix Guess');
    if ~exist('out')
       out=1;  % you need some default value if you ever reach this code without ever initializing out
    end
    return
end
out = newtraph(initialguess-(ht/dfunct(initialguess)), funct, dfunct);
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be a little late, but I think that it is important enough to deserve to be pointed out here. To make the recursion clearer I do recommend another approach here.

```
function out = newtraph(initialguess,funct,dfunct,counter)
maxCount = % yourValue;
ht = funct(initialguess);
if abs(ht) > 10^(-6) || abs(ht) < 10^6 || counter<maxCount % Break out after x tries
    counter = counter+1;
    out = newtraph(initialguess-(ht/dfunct(initialguess)), funct, dfunct,counter);
elseif abs(ht) < 10^(-6) %Tolerance
    out = initialguess;
else
    warning('Convergence were not reached!');
    out=0;
end
```

The preffered structure may be personal, but this way it is clear that you keep going until you hit a stop criterion, namely the function converged or were divergent.

Also, **recursive functions are dangerous due to that the only way to stop them is to fulfill the exit criterion or when the program crashes**. Matlab have a limit of how many times a recursion can go on and then throws an error. You will most likely want to handle the error by yourself (like you have done already by setting `out=0;`). Also matlabs limit is 500 recursive calls and you do most likely want to terminate the function earlier, maybe at 8-20 calls, depending on your algorithm.